# Don't or didn't

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

My friend said to me, "I have a shop in this place." I replied, "I thought you don't have one in this place".

Was I right? Or should I use *didn't* instead of *don't*?

Comment: I don't know if that is acceptable for a native speaker, but I'd definitely use the past tense.

Answer (score 3):

Use *didn't*, since you are reporting what you *thought* in the past.

Comment: I agree with this, "I *thought* you *didn't*" for past, or "I *think* you *don't*" for present.